# How to format a cell with data YYYYMMDD in Numbers to be a date type?

Tags: macos, numbers, formatting

I created a custom format to try and format a date column to be used within categories. However, Numbers tend to keep reverting my custom format to "Automatic" and I'm unable to group the data as part of a category.

How do I set cells to use my custom date format to be used in categories?

[image: Custom Format created]

Setting the field to use the new format
[image: Set Cell to new format]

Click away from the cell and go back to the field and see that the format has reverted back to "Automatic"
[image: Reverting format]

Comment: Have you tried to set it to a 'Date and Time' format and seeing if that works?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn’t detect the dates on the categories grouping which led me down this path of trying a custom format.

Comment: This is only on mac, right, not possible to create a custom format such as this date format, yyyy.mm.dd on ios/ipados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign you custom format to an empty cell. If you then enter a value that contains a hyphen (-) or a slash (/), such as "1/21/2019", Numbers assumes it’s a date and assigns it your custom date and time format automatically. And keeps it.

Otherwise, if you already have a number in a cell or enter value that is a number, such as "20171214", Numbers cannot recognize it as a date and assign it your custom date format.

Hope, this little video may help to understand as well: https://youtu.be/fUwRHtRLaec

Comment: Thank you, does this mean that I must re-type in the 7000+ records for numbers to recognise it? I've tried pasting it into a cell that I pre-format and its still having the same problem.